# User Control obstructing underlying User Control from recieving drag and drop content

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have an WPF application where there is a toolbox on the left with objects that you can drag and drop in a large area to the right. This large area is treated like a time line. There is a slider at the top that is used to scrub through the time line and there is a ruler across the bottom displaying time increments. In the middle, there is the area that receives the drag and drop content. The slider (top) and ruler (bottom) are contained in a scroll viewer, in their own separate user control, which sits "on top" of the drag and drop area. The problem is that the this user control is obstructing the drag and drop area from receiving its content. I tried experimenting with the "IsHitTestVisible" property on various elements and this did not help. When i disabled the IsHitTestVisible property on the proper elements, it allowed for the drag and drop ability that I was looking for, but then in turn disabled my slider and scroll viewer. Any ideas on how to bypass this problem? Thanks in advance!

-Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bypass... Just create a Drag and drop event on the "blocking" controls and route the event to your function.

Comment: Hi Josefvz, thanks this got me thinking in the right direction. Due to the way the drag and drop is being handled this would have have been a bit difficult, but instead I ended up throwing a drag event on the blocking control, which disables that control, allows the drop, and then added trip points when the user gets close to the slider or scrollbar, which re- enable the HitTestVisibility. Thanks again for setting me in the right direction.

Comment: @Matt No problem, glad that got you sorted!